# Forced down-casing in searches

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I am searching for `url:"*Prolog-inedit*"` which works. Note that the `P` is upper case. A search for a lower case `p` does not give a solution.  Now, after seeing the results for |relevance|, I want to switch to |newest| or |votes| or |active|. But when clicking on one of the other tabs, the query is downcased to `url:"*prolog-inedit*"`.

Comment: I didn't even think the searches were case-sensitive. I guess because you're using the `url` operator?

Comment: It appears to be just an issue with the link. Manually fixing the URL back to upper case to e.g. [`/search?tab=active&q=url%3a%22*Prolog-inedit*%22`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=url%3a%22*Prolog-inedit*%22) works.

Comment: Don't know when this was fixed, but it has been...

Comment: Please don't add such edits, if you want you can add this as new answer, quoting Oded's comment.

Comment: Solved! There is no longer any forced down-casing as [Oded remarks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122860/forced-down-casing-in-searches#comment778119_122860).